# Android change text size in TextView on click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I have few buttons containing only labels. They are made using 2 image resources (pressed is little bit bigger than not pressed)

```
button_image.png
button_image_pressed.png
```

and xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_image" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_image_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

And i want to use custom TextView insted of this.
Is it possible to chage TextView textSize when user touches text and change textSize back when text user releses screen?

I tried different solutions, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using an `onTouchListener()`.

```
    textView.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event ) {

            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    textView.setTextSize( ... );
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    textView.setTextSize( ... );
            }
            return false;
        }
    } );
```